# Expected end of statement in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VBscript. I am writing a script to read a registry. I have declared a variable but the browser shows an error **"Expected end of statement"**

This is my function :

```
<script type="text/vbscript">

  Function SayHello()
    MsgBox "Hello"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
uninstallRegKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\";
stdRegPro = "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\\\.\\root\\default:StdRegProv";

Set objReg=GetObject(stdRegPro)

objReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, uninstallRegKey, arrSubKeys
MsgBox arrSubKeys

  End Function

</script>
```

It gives error at declaring variable `uninstallRegKey` at the end of the statement (near semicolon)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this as a .vbs, a .hta, a .wsh, or a .htm(l) file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `;` statement delimiter in VBScript!

Comment: Thanks Jean-Francois :)